# How do I use properties to define a radial-gradient with React styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am new to functional programming, so I am having a lot of difficulty understanding how props are used with React's plugin, styled components.

I am trying to make the background of my website (a div) have a gradient. There are two radial-gradients that make up this gradient. The center of the radial-gradients, as well as the color of the radial-gradients are based off of properties that passed into the styled component. This is how I've tried to do it:

```
const backgroundChange = keyframes`
    0%, 100% {
        `background: ${(props) => radial-gradient(ellipse at props.xLeftPercent+'%' props.yLeftPercent)+'%', rgba(props.leftR + props.leftRStep * 0, props.leftG + props.leftGStep * 0, props.leftB + props.leftBStep * 0, 0.5), transparent),
                                  radial-gradient(ellipse at props.xRightPercent+'%' props.yRightPercent)+'%', rgba(props.rightR + props.rightRStep * 0, props.rightG + props.rightGStep * 0, props.rightB + props.rightBStep * 0, 0.5), transparent)`};
    50% {
        `background: ${(props) => radial-gradient(ellipse at props.xLeftPercent+'%' props.yLeftPercent)+'%', rgba(props.leftR + props.leftRStep * 50, props.leftG + props.leftGStep * 50, props.leftB + props.leftBStep * 50, 0.5), transparent),
                                  radial-gradient(ellipse at props.xRightPercent+'%' props.yRightPercent)+'%', rgba(props.rightR + props.rightRStep * 50, props.rightG + props.rightGStep * 50, props.rightB + props.rightBStep * 50, 0.5), transparent)`};
    }
`
```

I am given the error:

```
Unexpected token, expected ; (7:3)
```

Could anyone solve my syntax error for me, and could you also suggest some guides or documentation to look at to help me (styled-components documentation didn't really seem to be very useful for helping me here)?

Comment: I think the result should be a string: `background: ${(props) => `radial-gradient.......`}

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this comment since I realize that back quotes gray out text. I believe you meant this though (if there were back-quotes instead of single quotes && I've tried this and it doesn't work): 
'background: ${(props) => 'radial-gradient...'}
I've added a larger chunk of my code so you can see the whole thing (added to original post).

Comment: You are correct, I meant `'background: ${(props) => radial-gradient.......`}'` (replace the single quote with a back tick)
The value you return should be a string, unquoted text only works in template literals (like `styled.div'<style>'`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but these back-quotes still don't seem to work for me. I re-updated my code to what I suspect you are trying to convey to me.